# Copy Multiple files to another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which should:

1. Open the selected files
2. Copy the three tabs indicated to another workbook

I thought this was working ok but then I realized that it's copying the first selected file the same amount of times as the number of selected files.  So basically, it's not opening the other files and copying the tabs to the template.  Can you help?

```
Sub CopySheets()
Dim DialogBox As FileDialog
Dim FilePath, SheetName As String

Set DialogBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    DialogBox.Title = "Select Estimates to copy " & FileType
    DialogBox.AllowMultiSelect = True
    DialogBox.Filters.Clear
    DialogBox.Show

     If DialogBox.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
       FilePath = DialogBox.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

 For i = 1 To DialogBox.SelectedItems.Count

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

FilePath = DialogBox.SelectedItems(1)

SheetName1 = "Cover"
SheetName2 = "Summary"
SheetName3 = "Estimate and Schedule "

Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)

closedBook.Sheets(SheetName1).Copy 
After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

Range("B2:Z97").Select
Selection.Copy
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="zxc"
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets(SheetName1).Name = i 'I would like this to be the File Name

closedBook.Sheets(SheetName2).Copy 
After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

Range("B5:K39").Select
Selection.Copy
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="zxc"
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

closedBook.Sheets(SheetName3).Copy 
After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

Range("A3:M70").Select
Selection.Copy
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="zxc"
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

closedBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `FilePath = DialogBox.SelectedItems(1)` - `FIlePath` never changes.

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: I updated 
Dim DialogBox As FileDialog
Dim FilePath, SheetName As String

to

Dim DialogBox As FileDialog
Dim FilePath As Variant
Dim SheetName As String

but it didn't work either

Comment: Replace the 1 with i ... `FilePath = DialogBox.SelectedItems(i)`

Comment: That was Golden!!! Thank you soooo much!!!!